# Return a value from function without waiting for it to complete every time in Python

Tags: python

I've already read multiple forum threads, but still wanted to ask a specific question. Maybe someone can suggest something better.

So, there's a main loop which iterates through a list. The list itself is generated with a function which returns it in 30-50 seconds (after appending items to it). What is the best way to get the recent complete list without waiting for it to be generated when called every time?

Here's a simple example:

```
def check_list():
    list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    list_upd = []

    for i in list1:
        if 4 > i > 1:
            list_upd.append(i)
    return list_upd # return the updated list

while True:
    print("start") # we wait for 30 sec for the list to be generated

    for i in check_list():
         print(i)
    
    print("finish") # iterating through the list is completed
```

The idea is to be able to get the updated list no matter when you call the function without waiting for it to complete every time. It's not too important to get the latest generated list (previous one is fine too). A possible option is to write it to a file, then read it from there and update it in the background. Should probably use asyncio for it too. Are there some better options without writing to a file?

Thanks

Comment: What it sounds like you want is a [generator function](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)

Comment: Simple `yield i` instead of a list append should do it ?

Comment: With yield it just passes the list items from the function to the main loop when called? It doesn't return the complete list. That's a possible option though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this with a global var

```
def check_list():
    global list_upd    
    if 'list_upd' in globals():
        return list_upd 
    list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    list_upd = []

    for i in list1:
        if 4 > i > 1:
            list_upd.append(i)
    print("new list")
    return list_upd # return the updated list

while True:
    print("start") # we wait for 30 sec for the list to be generated

    for i in check_list():
         print(i)
    
    print("finish") # iterating through the list is completed
```

Edit a working solution for after the question was clarified using threads.

```
import threading
import time    
def check_list():
    global list_upd    
    if 'list_upd' in globals():
        return list_upd 
    list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    list_upd = []
    for i in list1:
        if 4 > i > 1:
            list_upd.append(i)
    print("new list")
    return list_upd
def thread_function():
    while True:
        global list_upd    
        list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        list_upd_2 = []
        for i in list1:
            if 4 > i > 1:
                list_upd_2.append(i)
        print("new list")
        list_upd=list_upd_2
        time.sleep(1)
   
x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function)
x.start()   
while True:
    print("start") # we wait for 30 sec for the list to be generated
    for i in check_list():
         print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("finish")
```

Comment: Using global is a good idea, thanks. How do I know when there's a updated list generated? It seems to print("new list") only once at the start? If the function fetches data from an external source and gathers it in a list depending on a few conditions for example. The values from the external source can change sometimes too, so would be good to know if it actually updates the list (even though it's not too important in this specific case).

Comment: the if just checks if "if 'list_upd' in globals():" just checks if it is ready to be returned but you could add another condition if you wanted

Comment: But the code after "if 'list_upd' in globals():" is running only once then? First we generate the list and it's stored in the global variable. Then it's returned using the global variable when the function is called. So, the list doesn't get updated anymore? There's no "new list" printed after the first run.

Comment: right if you want it to happen more you need to add another condition to the if the question seemed to think it was ok to use the old one you could set an async task going before you return if you want

Comment: Yes, the idea is to create a list and return it when the function is called. But, at the same time, keep updating it and update the global variable with the newly generated list in this case too.

Comment: you need to run another async task to keep updating the global var https://www.tutorialspoint.com/concurrency_in_python/concurrency_in_python_eventdriven_programming.htm. I thought you were just having trouble finding where to store the last run of the function

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks for checking it.

Comment: I added a threading solution. The time.sleep is just to slow it down to make it more readable

Comment: Thanks, I was using threading initially too :)